# JSONArray return null while parsing

Tags: android, json, api

I want to parse this JSON String :

```
{
  lhs: "1 British pound",
  rhs: "1.6152 U.S. dollars",
  error: "",
  icc: true
}
```

but JSONArray returns null value.

Comment: How can we help with no code?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/taF3qaaP

Comment: @Dave : http://pastebin.com/taF3qaaP

Answer (score 3):

current json string contain an `jsonObject` instead of `JsonArray` so parse it as :

```
// Convert String to Json Object
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("Pass_Your_Json_String");

// get lhs 
String str_lhs=jsonObject.getString("lhs");

// get rhs
String str_rhs=jsonObject.getString("rhs");

  //.....
```

Comment: +1 for pointing that there is no JSONArray present. To add JSONArray will be in `[]` and JSONObject will be in `{}`.

Comment: @samadhanmedge : In current code link you are retuning null from `doInBackground` change it to return an ArrayList list of parsed values to onPostExecute and remove `runOnUiThread` beuase we can access UI from `onPostExecute` without using runOnUiThread

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K: Ok, I got it, next time I'll remember this thing.

Comment: @samadhanmedge, remember to accept this answer. It makes SO work.